# How to access the `copy` function in the Chrome Developer Console when it's being overridden by `<symbol id="copy">`?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If you open the console in most websites and type `copy`, you get the 
 function.

[image]

However, in the [Discourse](https://meta.discourse.org/) website you get a symbol with an id of `copy`:

[image]

Is there a way to reference the original copy function that is being overridden by the symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That DOM element creates a global variable on `window` (per [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)), which overrides the command line API `copy` function, and AFAICT [there's no alternative alias](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/inspector/v8-console.cc?l=745&rcl=c761cf3374440d36f0cd964e92187339b6e8beb3). We'll have to temporarily delete the element.

1. right-click on `<symbol......` in the console, click "Delete"
2. type `_copy=copy` in the console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. switch to Elements panel, click on any element and press the Undo key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

Now you can use `_copy('foo')` to access the native function.